# Using split with regex to analyze a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have the following strings:

```
-8/12
3/*13
9/10/12
-9/*10/11
```

I would like to split them into array as follow:

```
-8/12     --> [-,8,12]
3/*13     --> [3,13]
9/10/12   --> [9,10,12]
-9/*10/11 --> [-,9,10,11]
```

I use this pattern to split:

```
"(?<=)(/\\*)?"
```

It doesn't work completely as expected, any ideas how to improve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just include `-` inside the lookbehind and make `\\*` as optional with a pipe character `|` separate the both.

```
string.split("(?<=-)|/\\*?");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR9rI5/1)

Comment: Perfect answer!! Thank you very much :-)